# How can I improve research speed in Stronghold Kingdoms?

Tags: stronghold-kingdoms

After completing a large number of researches in Stronghold Kingdoms, the time needed increases substantially. Right now, it takes me 9 hours. Are there any ways to speed up the process?

Answer (score 5):

In official [Stronghold Kingdoms FAQ](http://help.strongholdkingdoms.com/index.php/FAQ:Research,_ranks_and_honour#How_long_does_it_take_to_research_a_technology.3F) they suggest reaserching **Mathematics** to shorten reaserch time. **Math** reduces the research time [by **5% every level** its researched](http://strongholdkingdomsadvguide.com/research_education.html) to **max 50%** bonus.

Comment: I'm afraid the bonus given by Mathematics is more than nullified by the malus from researching anything: The malus is more than 5%. If I have to put 8 levels in just to get a 50% bonus, it would be better to ignore Mathematics completely, no?